# General coordinates and orthogonality

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differentiation

To my understanding, generalized coordinates may be chosen so that the basis vectors have components in other basis vectors. They may even be parallel and can basically look however one would like them to look.

Why is it then that:

$$\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{ \partial x^{\nu}}~=~\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}\ ?$$

This would seem to be false if there was some component of $x^{\mu}$ in $x^{\nu}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}f(x)
$$
means "derivative with respect to $x^\nu$ while keeping the rest of coordinates fixed".

Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{ \partial x^{\nu}}=\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}
$$
holds by definition.